# How can extend in proper way some php classes for have access from child class to all public methods from other child class?

Tags: php, methods, public, extends

What wrong in above classes? Basically i want to have access from Audi, Ford, Opel classes to all or both 3 classes (public methods).
For example in one of Audi object method to have access to Opel public methods like:

[in Audi] function otherPrices() { return $this->opel->getPrice(); }

```
class Car {
    function Car() {}
}
class Model extends Car {
    public $audi;
    public $ford;
    public $opel;

    function Model() {
        parent::Car();

        $this->audi = new Audi();
        $this->ford = new Ford();
        $this->opel = new Opel();
    }

}
class Factory {
    public $audi;
    public $ford;
    public $opel;
    function Factory(){
        $model = new Model();

        $this->audi = $model->audi;
        $this->ford = $model->ford;
        $this->opel = $model->opel;
    }
}
class Audi extends Factory {
    public $price = 10;
    function Audi() {}
    function audiVsOpel(){
        return "A:" . ($this->price - $this->opel->price);
    }
}
class Ford extends Factory {
    public $price = 12;
    function Ford() {}
    function fordVsAudi(){
        return "B:" . ($this->price - $this->audi->price);
    }
}
class Opel extends Factory {
    public $price = 14;
    function Opel() {}
    function opelVsford(){
        return "C:" . ($this->price - $this->ford->price);
    }
}

/*
Here a implementation
*/
$factory = new Factory();
echo $factory->audi->audiVsOpel(); // want to echo -4
echo $factory->ford->fordVsAudi(); // want to echo 2
echo $factory->opel->opelVsford(); // want to echo 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a getter in your class Factory :

```
public function getFactory($factory) {
    if (NULL === $this->{$factory}) {
        $this->{$factory} = new $factory;
    }
    return $this->{$factory};
}
```

And then get your different factory objects in each factory Classes this way :

```
$this->getFactory('opel')->price
```

Working exemple from your code :

```
class Car {
    function Car() {}
}
class Model extends Car {
    public $audi;
    public $ford;
    public $opel;

    function Model() {
        parent::Car();

        $this->audi = new Audi();
        $this->ford = new Ford();
        $this->opel = new Opel();
    }

}
class Factory {
    public $audi = NULL;
    public $ford = NULL;
    public $opel = NULL;
    function Factory(){
        $model = new Model();

        $this->audi = $model->audi;
        $this->ford = $model->ford;
        $this->opel = $model->opel;
    }

    public function getFactory($factory) {
        if (NULL === $this->{$factory}) {
            $this->{$factory} = new $factory;
        }
        return $this->{$factory};
    }
}
class Audi extends Factory {
    public $price = 10;
    function Audi() {}
    function audiVsOpel(){
        return "A:" . ($this->price - $this->getFactory('opel')->price);
    }
}
class Ford extends Factory {
    public $price = 12;
    function Ford() {}
    function fordVsAudi(){
        return "B:" . ($this->price - $this->getFactory('audi')->price);
    }
}
class Opel extends Factory {
    public $price = 14;
    function Opel() {}
    function opelVsford(){
        return "C:" . ($this->price - $this->getFactory('ford')->price);
    }
}

/*
Here a implementation
*/
$factory = new Factory();
var_dump($factory);
echo $factory->audi->audiVsOpel(); // echo -4
echo $factory->ford->fordVsAudi(); // echo 2
echo $factory->opel->opelVsford(); // echo 2
```

Comment: Nice, iI knew there was a factory problem. :D Thanks, work.